# Can I change APN settings from within app?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

My app, makes use of APN services. At first launch, it sends a

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

request. This triggers a system alert with permission request. No matter what the user chooses, it will be possible to change it from Settings, notification pane. The app gets the notifications and everything seems to work fine.

Now I have been asked to place a switch inside the app to activate/deactivate push notifications from inside the app. 
I don't think this is possible, but before answering I'd like to get a confirmation.

Is there a way to access (read and/or write) notification permissions related to a specific app from within the app itself (just like app defaults preferences)?
Is there a way to delete the app from the list of the apps which need push notifications once it has been added due to the initial request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as it is a system setting relating to your app rather than an app setting. Otherwise any app could automatically enable all its notifications whenever launched, which would cause havoc.

Edit:
You can read your app's permissions using `UIRemoteNotificationType enabledTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];` and then performing a bitwise and operation with the different types to see which are enabled.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So it's possible to read, and not possible to write these permissions, right? What about removing the app from the list?

Comment: You can only read, but you can call `unregisterForRemoteNotifications`.